# Recursive get ID

Tags: c#, list, children

haloa!

i have a `List<Channel>` where `Channel` is a custom class offcourse:

```
public class Channel 
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long parentID { get; set; }
}
```

strcuture can be something like:

```
ID = 1, parentID = 0
    ID = 64, parentID = 1
        ID = 28, parentID = 64
        ID = 36, parentID = 64
ID = 5, parentID = 0
```

and so on.

what i would like to do is get all children ID's of a specific channel:

```
function List<long> getChildrenIDS (long ID)
{
    // WHAT GOES HERE?
}
```

Comment: And do you want the children of the children as well? Please add another level to the sample data and list the desired output.

Comment: The ID 28 is repeated, is this a mistake?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to get this to work if the `Channel` had a `List<Channel> Children { get; private set; }`?

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, all children of the current channel.
@GeorgeDuckett - it is a mistake, edited.
@Oliver - no, since this is just a sample of the code so you could understand what i want, in RL, i dont have a `List<Channel>`

Comment: Whats up with the downvote storm ? isnt this a legit question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all children:

```
public IEnumerable<long> GetChildren(List<Channel> list, long id)
{
  foreach(Channel c in list)
    if(c.parentID == id)
      yield return c.ID;
}
```

Build this as returning an `IEnumerable<long>` rather than returning a `List<long>` as then calling code that needs a `List<long>` can use either `new List<long>(GetChildren(list, id))` or `GetChildren(list, id).ToList()`, while calling code that doesn't need this can get better performance in memory and time to first result by not building a list it doesn't actually need, as in `foreach(long childID in GetChildren(list, id))`.

To get all descendants (children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc.) which is the only case we could make any use of recursion (as per your question title) use:

Assuming there cannot be duplicates (same grandchild through multiple routes):

```
private IEnumerable<long> GetDescendants(List<Channel> list, long id)
{
   foreach(long child in GetChildren(list, id))
   {
     yield return child;
     foreach(long grandchild in GetDescendants(list, child))
       yield return grandchild;
   }
}
```

If there can be duplicates then you could apply `.Distinct()` to the above, or go for:

```
private IEnumerable<long> GetDescHelper(List<Channel> list, long id, HashSet<long> already)
{
  foreach(long child in GetChildren(list, id))
    if(already.Add(child))
    {
      yield return child;
      foreach(long desc in GetDescHelper(list, child, already))
        yield return desc;
    }
}
public IEnumerable<long> GetDescendants(List<Channel> list, long id)
{
  return GetDescHelper(list, id, new HashSet<long>());
}
```

This said, I would probably rather model this by having the Channel classes maintain a `List<Channel>` of children.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if Marcos answer really produces the desired result, but i would write this in a more LINQish fashion:

```
private IEnumerable<long> GetChildrenIds(IEnumerable<Channel> channels, long parentId)
{
    if(channels == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("channels");

    var childs = channels.Where(c => c.ParentId == parentId)
                         .Select(c => c.Id);

    return childs;
}
```

If you also need the deep nested ones you could maybe use this function:

```
private IEnumerable<long> GetAllChildrenIds(IEnumerable<Channel> channels, long parentId)
{
    var childs = GetChildrenIds(channels, parentId);
    var alldescendants = childs.SelectMany(id => GetAllChildrenIds(channels, id));

    return childs.Concat(alldescendants);
}
```

But be aware that it doesn't check for cyclic redundancy and could end up in an stackoverflow exception!

Comment: Yes, my answer works (I've tried) but your solution is really nice!! :)

Comment: wont this get only the immediate children? what about the deep nested ones?

Answer (score 0):

Having

```
List<Channel> list = new List<Channel>();
List<long> ret = new List<long>();
```

in your class, you can do:

No recursion (so only children)

```
private List<long> GetChildrenIds(long parentId)
{
    list.ForEach(p => { if (p.parentID == parentId) ret.Add(p.ID); });
    return ret;
}
```

or with recursion (children of children too)

```
private List<long> GetChildrenIds(long parentId)
{
    list.ForEach(p => { if (p.parentID == parentId) { 
                            ret.Add(p.ID); 
                            GetChildrenIds(p.ID); 
                        } 
                      });
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: @Dementic: take a look at my edited code. Is this what you need?

Comment: Having ret in your class introduces a concurrency issue (two threads will be adding to the same list) and a bug where calling the method twice will have the results of both calls, since ret is never cleared. Since ret has nothing to do with the class, but only with the particular call, it should be a local created in the method itself.